# WAMP 2.4 installation of joomla 2.5.14 stuck on step 4 (database)

Tags: joomla2.5, wampserver

I saw similar questions but any of them has not correct answer. The installation of Joomla on localhost does not proceed after step 4. Database Configuration.

```
WAMPSERVER version 2.4
Apache 2.4.4
PHP 5.4.12
MySQL 5.6.12
Joomla_2.5.14-Stable-Full_Package
```

Answer (score 2):

The usual reason for this is simply that php runs out of execution time.

Check your php.ini file ( use the wampmanager menus so you edit the correct version of this )

```
left click wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
```

This will open notepad on the correct php.ini file, look for this directive

```
max_execution_time = 60
```

Change it to something larger like

```
max_execution_time = 240
```

Then retry your install.

Remember to set it back to 60 after the install completes

Answer (score 0):

if you edit the SQL install file (Root/installation/SQL/mysql/joomla.sql) in something like notepad++ and replace all "ENGINE=InnoDB" with "ENGINE=MyIsam" the DB type is more responsive to the Joomla install conditions.